# Help with compromised phone Android 7.0

Tags: security, lock-screens, 7.0-nougat

I want to ask if there's any way I can get rid of whatever's allowing my phone to be unlocked easily without any resetting or Google account?

My phone has been messed with and now it keeps getting unlocked no matter what I try, whether I put a lock-screen or change my Google password.

I don't think they would use spyware because it would cost money, but maybe they would but I think they did some configurations and/or exploited something in my phone for it to be unlocked easily.

Can anyone help me know what it is and tell me on how to get rid of it? Thanks

EDIT: My phone keeps getting unlocked because it's compromised which is why the lockscreen doesn't work as it should or it just keeps getting bypassed.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217872

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217890/help-with-compromised-phone-android-7-0